# PHP contact form handler not working?

Tags: php, forms, email, redirect, handler

I need a very simple, but effective PHP form handler that will work with this form:

```
<form id="contact" method="post" action="contact_handle.php">
<label for="name">Name:</label>
<input type="text" class="text_style" placeholder="John Doe" name="name" /><br />
<label for="email">Email:</label> 
<input type="email" class="text_style" placeholder="email@example.com" name="email" /><br />   
<label for="message">Subject:</label>
<textarea class="areawidth" rows="4" name="message" /></textarea><br />
<button id="contactbutton" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This is what I currently have but it doesn't send an email and it doesn't redirect like I intended. And I cant seem to figure out whats going on.

```
<?php  
$invalid = '';
$my_email = 'my@email.com'; 

// Validate input:
if(empty($_POST['name'])  ||
   empty($_POST['email']) ||
   empty($_POST['message']))
{
    $invalid.= "\n All fields are required";
}
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];   

// Validate email:
if (!preg_match(
"/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i",
$email))
{
    $invalid .= "\n Invalid email address";
}

// Send email if no errors detected:
if( empty($invalid))
{
$to = $my_email;
$subject = "Contact form submission: $name";
$body = "You have received a new message. ".
" Here are the details:\n Name: $name \n ".
"Email: $email\n Message:\n $message";
$headers = "From: $email\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email";
mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);  

//redirect to the thank you page:    
header('Location: contact_thanks.php');
}
?>
```

When it is submitted it takes me to contact_handle.php that displays blank and fails to redirect.

Comment: Are you testing this on your localhost or a live server? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: There seems to be a typo on line 10 of your form handler - you're storing the error message in `$error` variable, whereas it should probably be `$invalid`, which is what the rest of the code uses.

Comment: Oops, Fixed the typo, Still the same outcome though. I tested both on localhost and live server, neither of which work. No error messages displaying. Just a blank screen and no email.

Comment: add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of `contact_handle.php`.  I think a fatal error is occurring and your settings are preventing it from showing anything.  Or it appears, if you have an invalid form, nothing is printed and no redirect takes place.

Comment: where this $email_address came from ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the redirect has to be the first output to the browser, so if anything else is being output it won't work.

why don't you just include the thank you page rather than redirecting to it, ie.

```
include 'contact_thanks.php';
```

Comment: This made the form work! Thank you! I should have done this in the first place. I have my website already templated with PHP so the simple include is much easier. Sorry I can't vote you up, I don't have enough points yet.

Answer (score 1):

If you're providing all of the code, the issue is that your form is throwing an error (by adding text to `$invalid`, but there is no code to handle `$invalid` *not* being empty. To solve this, add this after the closing `}` at the end:

```
echo $invalid;
```

Comment: Thank you, form now shows errors if any. Simple mistake should have been easy to notice.